# Can all elements of one class be put into the same position?

Tags: html, css, class, text, centering

I am wondering if there is any way I can make every element of a certain class to be at the same position? What I am trying to do is when you hover a certain image I want text about that image to appear in a central location between all the other images. I know how to do this by hard coding each element's position, but that is a pain and isn't good practice using in-line styling.

**So my question is: How can I make every element of a certain class be put in the same position?**

Here is the example: http://homeinspectioncarync.com/testpage/

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/3/000/00c/2ab/35ae340.jpg" class="images">
  <p class="fixed">Dave</p>
  <p class="para name">Dave</p>
  <p class="para title" ">Senior Inspector</p> 
<p class ="para bio " >"This is an example of a Bio. We need to get a bio for each one of our inspectors in order to complete this page! "</p> 
</div> 
<div class="image-container "> 
<img src="http://homeinspectionraleighnc.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Glenns-Photo-1.png " class="images "> 
<p class="fixed ">Glenn</p> 
<p class="para name " >Glenn </p> 
<p class ="para title " >Senior Inspector</p> 
<p class ="para bio " >"Licensed: State Home Inspector, General Contractor, Sub-surface Waste Water Inspector. Part owner and senior inspector, responsible for maintaining the highest quality of the field inspections, including both the comprehensiveness
    of the inspection itself and the interpersonal relationships with the client, realtor and all other personal involved in the inspection process. "</p> 
</div> 
<div class="image-container ">
<img src="https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p160x160/18718_2753855091076_8128390731521222770_n.jpg?oh=d1d49aea28d3cb6ff76033db1ae056ba&oe=57D998E2 " class="images "> <p class="fixed ">Spencer</p> 
<p class="para name " >Spencer</p>
 <p class ="para title " >Trainee</p> 
<p class ="para bio " >" "</p> 
</div> 
<div class="image-container "> 
<img src="https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c22.22.272.272/s160x160/166620_1817593049535_5878435_n.jpg?oh=78d8a42398b126fc1f75d1b32295029a&oe=57D73E8C " class="images "> <p class="fixed ">Chuck</p> 
<p class="para name ">Chuck </p> 
<p class ="para title " >Senior Inspector</p>
<p class ="para bio ">" "</p> 
</div> 
<div class="image-container "> 
<img src="http://homeinspectioncarync.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/trevor-e1464897672300.jpg " class="images "> 
<p class="fixed ">Trevor</p> 
<p class="para name ">Trevor </p> 
<p class ="para title " >Senior Inspector</p> 
<p class ="para bio " >" "</p> 
</div> 
<div class="image-container "> 
<img src="http://homeinspectioncarync.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/betterrob-e1464897851528.jpg " class="images "> <p class="fixed ">Rob</p> 
<p class="para name ">Rob </p> 
<p class ="para title " >Senior Inspector</p> 
<p class ="para bio " >" "</p> 
</div> 
<div class="image-container "> 
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d0/Chrome_Logo.svg/1024px-Chrome_Logo.svg.png " class="images "> 
<p class="fixed ">Anthony</p> 
<p class="para name " >Anthony</p> 
<p class ="para title " >Senior Inspector</p> 
<p class ="para bio " >" "</p> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.images {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-container:hover .images {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.para {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 200%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.image-container:hover .para {
  opacity: 1;
}

.para.name {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #01ba7c;
}

.para.title {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 170%;
  font-style: italic;
  color: grey;
}

.para.bio {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  color: #000000;
}

.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  color: #000000;
}
```

I would like for the .para.name's to all appear under the first row of images, in the center. The .para.title's and the .para.bio's should be in the center as well, but to the left of the .para.name's.

Thank you in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to `getElementsByClassName` using JavaScript, to iterate through returned collection and set the same position for each of the elements.

Something like [this](http://jsbin.com/cebexu/2/).

Note: I've set `position: fixed;` on classes you used, probably not what you want to do in this scenario, but if you tinker around you'll get what you needed.

Comment: how exactly would i go about setting the same position for each one? I've tried simply putting in top and left values into the css for each class, but what it does is move it that many pixels left and right of its starting position, not set it to the screen at that position

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Have you got the chance to look at the link I've added? There is "Edit in JS Bin" button in top right corner which will send you to editor once you click it, and you can see the full code there.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you remove the positioning on the image container and let them be positioned against a parent element like the row. The CSS would look something like this:

```
.et_pb_module {
  position: relative;
}

.images {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.image-container {
  margin-left: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-container:hover .images {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.para {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 200%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.image-container:hover .para {
  opacity: 1;
}

.para.name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50px;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #01ba7c;
}

.para.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50px;
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  font-size: 170%;
  font-style: italic;
  color: grey;
}

.para.bio {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50px;
  margin: 90px 0 0;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  color: #000000;
}

.fixed {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: #000000;
}
```

Because each element is being absolutely positioned, it won't be able to adjust it's rendering position based on things like line wrapping. This means you either need an extra line even if there isn't a second line or it will look broken. Ideally you would wrap .name, .title, and .bio in a container and position that absolutely so that you don't have to worry about the name or title wrapping.